# Binding 2 SQL queries into one datatable

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datatable

I am trying to bind two SQL query results to one `DataTable` so that I can set the `DataTable` as the data source of a chart, but I am unsure how to go about it. I cannot seem to add the SQL query results to the specific columns within the `DataTable` that I need.

Here is my code:

```
// retrieve connection from configuration settings 
connection = new SqlConnection(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DataConnectionString").ToString());

// Calling SQL query 
SqlCommand commandGraph = new SqlCommand("SELECT AtmosphericPressure FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time > '" + TextBox1_fromDate.Text + "' AND time < '" + TextBox2_toDate.Text + "';", connection);
commandGraph.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

SqlCommand commandGraph1month = new SqlCommand("SELECT AtmosphericPressure AS apMonth FROM Buoy3v3 WHERE time > (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox1_fromDate.Text + "')) AND time < (DATEADD(month, 1,'" + TextBox2_toDate.Text + "')) ;", connection);
commandGraph1month.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

//connection open
connection.Open();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("AP");
dt.Columns.Add("AP1month");


using (SqlDataReader reader = commandGraph.ExecuteReader())
{

dt.Load(reader);
}

using (SqlDataReader reader1 = commandGraph1month.ExecuteReader())
{
   dt.Load(reader1);
}

Chart1.DataSource = dt;

Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "AP";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "AP1month";

//connection close
connection.Close();
```

Comment: why not call it in one query?

Comment: If I called it in one query, would I be able to set the Y-axis on the chart to the two different time-constraints sets so that they run concurrently, to allow for comparison?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? In your chart x is value and y is day? Then for 1 y you will have 2 x - one from current month, one from next

Comment: I am trying to create a line graph where there are two lines, the first line representing a data parameters value over a certain time period e.g. 1-10-2013 to 10-10-21013, and the second line representing the same data parameters value over the same period plus one month e.g. 1-11-2013 to 10-11-2013, and have the two lines running side by side to allow for comparison.

Comment: The code posted here is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: I know, I just put it together quickly to ask the question, I will refactor it before I ever release it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use only one query. Something like this could work:

```
SELECT t1.AtmosphericPressure, t2.AtmosphericPressure
FROM Buoy3v3 t1
LEFT JOIN Buoy3v3 t2 ON t1.time = (DATEADD(month, 1,t2.time))
WHERE ...
```

This should result in 2 lines running alongside eachother - result could be looking something like this:

```
1 |  ..xxxxx    xxxxxxx
2 |   x.... x  x ......
3 |  x     . xx..
4 |         ...             
5 |_______________________
     1   2   3   4   5
```

In your code you are having just one column `AtmosphericPressure`. If you really want to use 2 queries you could make them return 2 columns -

```
SELECT AtmosphericPressure, null FROM Buoy3v3
SELECT null, AtmosphericPressure FROM Buoy3v3
```

This should result in in two lines, but the second will be starting where first ended

Also your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, please consider using parametrized queries - like `commandGraph.Parameters.Add()`

Comment: If I was to just have one query, how would I set my Y-axis to two separate lines?

Comment: added result chart representation, if its not looking how you want it pls post your representation in question

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble with the sql. Is the sql select statement completed with 'WHERE t1.time > '2012-10-01' AND t1.time < '2012-10-05' AND t2.time > '2012-11-01' t2.time < '2012-11-05' ;'?

Comment: @DaveMc yep you just miss one AND there